# What am I doing wrong? Works in JSFiddle not in my html page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So, I've been fiddling a bit with this redirect generator in jsfiddle and got what I wanted. I'm trying to create a html page with it but I'm having trouble getting it to work.
http://jsfiddle.net/wVUhN/2/

I'm still fairly new to jquery.
My redirect.html page code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Redirect Test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#submit").click(function(){
    theurl = $("#theurl").val();
    $("textarea#newvalue").val('<html><head><meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL="'+theurl+'"></head><body>This page has been moved.<p><a href="'+theurl+'">IF YOU ARE NOT REDIRECTED, PLEASE CLICK HERE.</a></body></html>');    
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="theurl" placeholder="enter URL" /><button id="submit">Create Redirect</button>
<br>
<textarea id="newvalue"></textarea>


</body>
</html>
```

LIVE URL: http://buildlinux.com/frontline/redirect.html

Comment: And what exactly not working correctly?

Comment: *How* doesn't it work? What's in the JS console?

Comment: I added the live URL to the post, when the button is clicked nothing happens.

Comment: In his fiddle the code is executed `onload`. In his site he put the script in the head so it's executed before the DOM is ready.

Comment: I've added the code inside the body tag, same issue though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your code within document ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // ...
})
```

Alternatively, the shorter method:

```
$(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        theurl = $("#theurl").val();
        $("textarea#newvalue").val('<html><head><meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL="' + theurl + '"></head><body>This page has been moved.<p><a href="' + theurl + '">IF YOU ARE NOT REDIRECTED, PLEASE CLICK HERE.</a></body></html>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this as well, no change.

Comment: @Vernard Seems to work now on [the page](http://buildlinux.com/frontline/redirect.html)

Comment: @Vernard Check your browser console: `TypeError: $ is not a function` Remove the `noConflict`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the custom script in the end of the  `<body>` (before `</body>`), or do it with .onload. It works in JSfiddle, because there is onLoad option, set by default.

Comment: Ok, I moved the script inside the body tags but no change. The issue is still persistent. Any ideas? @divoom12